# Creating new vertices where meshes join

Tags: mesh, geometry

When I join the the meshes, is there a way to create a new seam along where they join, to then remove the internal geometry and get an accurate volume estimation for the new mesh?

It's the diamond shape and the smaller cylinder. I can see a trace of where the two intersect but there doesn't seem to be an actual join as when I remove the lower vertices of the cylinder in the diamond after joining it removes the edges all the way up to the higher vertices.

[image]

Hope this is clear!

Comment: Hello :). You need to physically join the meshes (using Boolean or similar tool). So far, you only 'grouped' your meshes into one object.

Comment: Oh thank you! So simple, I knew there must have been an easy way to do this, google kept pointing me to complex solutions.